# .netstandard library and UniversalApiContract

Tags: c#, asynchronous, uwp, portable-class-library, .net-standard

I'm building a **.NETStandard** library (version 1.3),
using async await inside the library works fine until i add a reference to **Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract**.
After adding this reference i get errors on every await keyword inside my code

this is the error

> 'IAsyncAction' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no
>   extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type
>   'IAsyncAction' could be found

this is the code i need to run

```
await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Low, () => { OnUserChanged?.Invoke(user); });
```

removing the **await** keyword result in a working code, but i get this warning

> Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method
>   continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await'
>   operator to the result of the call.

How can i solve this?

Comment: You shouldn't add such a reference if it is UWP specific.

Comment: Your library isn't going to be "standard" at all when you hard-code a WinRT type like CoreApplication.  And async/await does work very differently under the hood in a UWP app, nothing particularly obvious from the keywords.  Since it is only ever going to work in a UWP app, do consider using the "Class Library (Universal Windows)" project template to get ahead.

Comment: the problem is that I need to rais this event and this event is going to modify an object on the UI thread. If I'm not going to use "CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync" i got a cross thread access

Comment: How do you "add a reference to Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract"? - I don't think this is appropriate for a netstandard library.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `using System;` at the top of your code file. That has the extension required to turn `IAsyncAction` to a `Task`.

If that doesn't work, try this statement (just to see if the code compiles and runs):

```
var a = CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Low, () => { OnUserChanged?.Invoke(user); });

await System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions.AsTask(a);
```

If the above doesn't work for you, then try temporarily upgrading to .Net Standard 1.4 (again, just to see if it compiles and runs)

And if that doesn't work, then there might be something messed up with the library references.

Comment: It's the first thing that i have checked and the using was there

Comment: Do you see `System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions.GetAwaiter(..)`?

Comment: I only got the error in the description "'IAsyncAction' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IAsyncAction' could be found"

Comment: Updated my answer to help with some debugging.

Comment: WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions doesn't exist

Comment: Ok, maybe you can elaborate in your question how you added the references.